# One question(now): Read all files in a folder, line by line

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Medium = Python

Problem 1.(main problem) I am trying to do a line by line read of all files in a specific directory. However, after the first file is read the second does not open.

Problem 2.(SOLVED) Outputing Date as a filename. Code below does that now. (Rafael helped)

The code that I originally had wrote worked perfectly for 1 file, however, when I tried to add multiple file functionality by giving a path to the directory, then going through each file in said directory, the program is only able to read one of the files.

1.) To try to fix the multiple files problem, I thought that maybe the readlines function list that is created when trying to reinstance/read a new file needed to be cleared or deleted. (however it still would have passed the initial open file if that was the case.)(Also I was originally testing with three files hence the print(files[0] - [3]).

```
import os
import sys
import datetime

def main():

    date_object = datetime.date.today()
    dateString = date_object.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    print(dateString)
    dateString = dateString + ".txt"
    print(dateString)
    fileWrite = dateString


    #open or create fileWrite
    try:
        fW = open(fileWrite, "a+")
    except IOError:
        print ("Did not create File: " + fileWrite)
        sys.exit()

    #walks through all files in folder SeperateProject/Devices
    #path = 'Test path to directory here'
    #path = 'C:/Users/Bosborne/Desktop/Circuits/SeparateProject/Devices'
    files = os.listdir(path)  # Get all the files in that directory
    print("Files in '%s': %s" % (path, files))
    print(files[0], files[1], files[2])
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        fileRead = filename

        #add in ability to Walk through device list (.txt)
        #create error catches here
        try:
            fR = open(filename, "r")
        except IOError:
            print ("Could not open File: " + filename)
            sys.exit()
        try:
            fRead = fR.readlines()
        except IOError:
            print ("Could not read File: " + filename)
            sys.exit()

        #add walk through list to DEV
        DEV = filename
        #show list of included devices
        print(DEV)

        #Tried to fix the error of not being able to open file 2
        fRead.clear()
        del fRead[:]

        fR.close()
        print("close fileRead")
    fW.close()
    print("close fileWrite")
    return


#run main
if(__name__ == '__main__'):
        main();
```

Expected it to be able to open each file in the directory since it does #retrieve the correct name of each file as it checks all files in directory. (Fails to open the second file)
Here is some OUTPUT

PS C:\Users\Bosborne\Desktop\Circuits\SeparateProject> python .\TestOPEN.py

05-21-2019

05-21-2019.txt

Files in 'C:/Users/Bosborne/Desktop/Circuits/SeparateProject/Devices': 
['001p01.txt', '001p02.txt', '001p03.txt']

001p01.txt 001p02.txt 001p03.txt

001p01txt

close fileRead

Could not open File: 001p02.txt

PS C:\Users\Bosborne\Desktop\Circuits\SeparateProject>

Comment: I think your problem with the filename = date has to do with the `/` not being a valid character for a file on Windows.

Comment: That solved the filename to date problem. Thanks, I'll update the code so that part works. (If I can figure out how to edit my main question) :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to open/read each file as if they were in the cwd instead of doing a os.path.join in my open statement.

fR = open(os.path.join(path, filename), "r")